# Global user access to a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I have a new database that needs to be accessible by everyone on our team. However, when I created the database as a non-root user, other users are unable to see the newly created database. I don't want to individually grant privileges to users, especially when new users get added. Talk about a maintenance nightmare. I know this can be done, because the dev before me made this happen, and is unavailable for me to ask him at the moment.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

**SOLVED**
Thanks everyone. Blunt advice of just doing it manually seems to be the way to do it.

Comment: Just define one user and grants perms over the database...and all use that user(something like dev_user account)

Comment: either you grant access to all your users directly, or you provide access for ONE account and then provide some OTHER means of interfacing to the db.